# Not able to add S3 as destination in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda. And added API gateway as Add Triggers.

Now I want to add *S3 bucket* to Add destination so that *S3 bucket* can store the data which I will be posting through my API. But when I try to add S3 , It throws the error

> The provided destination config
>   DestinationConfig(onSuccess=OnSuccess(destination=arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname),
>   onFailure=null) is invalid.

[click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFy85.png)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use s3 directly as a destination from your lambda.
Destination can be an SQS queue, SNS topic, Lambda function, or EventBridge event bus.

What you can do in order to store data to s3 from your lambda is to do that through your code inside lambda.

You can follow this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Answer (score 0):

As Xanthos Symeou said:

> You cannot use s3 directly as a destination from your lambda. The destination can be an SQS queue, SNS topic, Lambda function, or EventBridge event bus.

But he has provided a link for **How to add S3 as a trigger**. You want to add s3 as a destination so you can follow this link:

[Use AWS Lambda to Append Daily Data to CSV File in S3 Bucket](https://medium.com/@haldis444/use-lambda-to-append-daily-data-to-csv-file-in-s3-2c2813bc33d0)

Here in this tutorial. He has shown how to append, but if you don't want to append, you can make the changes into the code accordingly.